# Bingo based on number of hits on card?

Tags: probability

I was wondering how many possible combinations there were to win based on the number of hits on a bingo card (25 spots, 1-75 etc.)?

I know that if you get 1,2,3 hits on the card, there are no chances of bingo because you need at least 5 spots (4 with the free space) to get a bingo. Once you get to 4 hits, there are 4 ways of getting a bingo (horizontally/vertically/diagonally across the free space), but how would you calculate for 5 and onwards?

I count 12, but http://www.durangobill.com/BingoHowTo.html says there is 88.
Is there a way to calculate it? Thanks for stopping by.

Comment: Even how you would figure out the total number of combinations without having to count would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

To count the ways to win with $5$ spots, you can either have a line that goes through the center plus one extra spot or one that does not go through the center.  For each of the four lines that go through the center, there are $20$ choices for the extra spot, giving $4 \cdot 20 =80$.  There are four vertical lines that do not go through the center plus four horizontal lines that do not go through the center.  The total is then $88$.